# R knitr markown: Setting HTML page width

Tags: css, r, knitr

I am using `knitr` to create a HTML webpage. The default setting seems to be 800px but I need a larger page size of 1100px

```
body {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    line-height: 20px ; 
}
```

I have tried:

```
library("markdown")
library("knitr")
knit2html("test.Rmd",options = c(width=1100))
```

But this still gives me the smaller page size of 800px

How can I set the code for the HTML page width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `css` element to your document, e.g.

```
---
title: "test"

output:
  html_document:
    css: "test.css"
---
```

and then put your new css information in that file, e.g.

```
body {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
 padding: 1em;
 line-height: 20px ; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason this didn't work for me but then I tried: <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet"> which worked fine.

Comment: This only works if I add the `!important` rule to the `max-width` definition as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38373846/7196903). Using that rule [seems bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception), so is there another way?

Comment: This also didn't work for me (nothing changed). @adam.888 could you share where/how you added "<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">" to make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for whom are struggling with widths in 2022 below my code that I put after YAML:

```
<style>
    .main-content, .toc {
      max-width: 90rem;
      padding: 2rem 4rem;
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-size: 1.1rem;
    }
</style>
```

That finally works for me.